# Where can I find a working port range scanner?

Tags: windows, python, 32-bit

Either for win32 or Python. There are so many port scanner python scripts and NONE of them work without some python knowledge.  If you're going to post a port scanner py script please test it.

Angry IP scanner does not do single hosts with large port ranges.
Nmap does not seem to even find any OPEN ports on some of my remote hosts, which just isn't the case.

I dare someone to show me one that works. I have a number of VPS's with providers that offer hardware firewall services that I need to make sure work.

Comment: Nmap should just work, there is something wrong with your machine or perhaps your network is too secure.

Comment: I think the assumption that "everything tried doesn't work as expected means that everything tried is broken" is less likely to be true than the expectation of what should happen being incorrect.  Something in your environment is perhaps causing the problem.  Perhaps expand your question with details about the server being tested, the expected results, and what you get - from nmap particularly as it is a familiar tool to many.

Comment: With respect to nmap and remote hosts, typically ICMP packets will be dropped by edge security devices such as firewalls. Try re-running nmap with the -Pn flag to skip host discovery (ping).

Answer (score 3):

[Nmap](http://nmap.org) is the best tool for this that I have found.
Lots of options, runs fast, and can do TCP, UDP, and ICMP scans.

EDIT: The problems you say you've had with Nmap may be because of a blocking router on your network. Try scanning `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) and see if it finds anything

Answer (score 0):

I am beginning a new service that will allow people to scan open ports an IP ranges all online for free. Also it logs all of the open ports found allowing you and other to search by host name/IP or by open port number. I am adding new featuresas I think on them.
Link: http://arehost.net:9090/port_scanner/